# How can I rate-limit my Flask application per user?

Tags: python, flask, web, backend, rate-limiting

https://flask-limiter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

I am looking at Flask-Limiter's documentations and I'm unable to find how to rate-limit per user, everything is globally. Example, Instead of setting it to max 200 requests by all users, how can I make it 200 requests per day by a single user? (IP, or any other identification I don't know what's used)

Comment: Usually rate-limits are based on IP, when I check the documentation it says the same, Can you tell what is your need exactly? Lets say there are two users Alice and Bob, will they have same rate-limit 200 and 200 or Alice has 100 Bob has 200 etc. ?

Comment: @ibrahim-dogan Lets say user 1 is spamming my endpoint with requests, I'd like to rate-limit them but let user 2 still use the endpoint normally, because they aren't spamming it.

Comment: by default all the rate limiters work as you mentioned so if you go with the simple version it will be okay as well. Usually rate limits apply per minute btw. Search more for best practices. You can also search it as `throttle`.

Comment: @ibrahim-dogan i have tested this one https://flask-limiter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ and it doesn't work the way i described in the reply. when i got ratelimited on my local IP I was still ratelimited on a vpn. do you know any other ones that work with flask?

Comment: can you create an endpoint and return the value of `flask_limiter.util.get_ipaddr()` this output to see the ip address with and without vpn.

Comment: returns 127.0.0.1 (localhost) both with and without an VPN

Comment: that is what i have expected, how you connect to your local server with vpn? if with tunnel like ngrok etc it might be the reason. you do not have to change anything, it works normally. if you still want to test it, test it with live server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this in the [recipes](https://flask-limiter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#rate-limit-key-functions):

> Rate limiting a route by current user (using [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)):

```
@route("/test")
@login_required
@limiter.limit("1 per day", key_func = lambda : current_user.username)
def test_route():
    return "42"
```

---

**UPDATED**: added simple example

Here is a simple Flask app implementing the recipe to give you better idea:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect
from flask_login import (
    LoginManager, 
    UserMixin, 
    current_user, 
    login_required,
    login_user, 
    logout_user
)
from flask_limiter import Limiter                    

app = Flask(__name__)

# flask-login
app.secret_key = 'super secret string' 
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

# flask-limiter
limiter = Limiter(app)

# user class
class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self.username = id

# memory storage
users = [User('user')]

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return users[0]

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello, World!'

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        login_user(users[0])
    return redirect('/secured')

@app.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect('/')

@app.route('/secured')
@login_required
@limiter.limit("2 per day", key_func = lambda : current_user.username)
def secured():
    return f"Hello, {current_user.id}"

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    app.run()
```

Comment: I have tried the code and made minor changes to it because flask-login exceptions told me to. Currently it just redirects me to the same page like 50 times, this is my current code (just the relevant parts) https://mystb.in/FranchiseOriginalRca.coffeescript , how can I fix this?

Comment: I've updated my answer with full example. Hope it helps

Comment: It might also be helpful to  attach it to a external data store such as MongoDB (cause if we store it in memory, the rate limiting won't work in a distributed system where each VM/Container etc. is ephemeral in nature).